# Why can I not combine if and eval? And whats the best alternative?

Tags: asp.net

In a Asp Net data bound control one can use the nice Eval() syntax:

```
<div><%# Eval("MyProp") %></div>
```

but it's not possible to combine with a conditional statement is it?:

```
<% if (Eval("MyProp")!="") { %>
<div><%# Eval("MyProp") %></div>
<%} %>
```

Would be nice to have that option.

So - my option is to put part of the markup in CodeBehind. I really liked to keep it out of there. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Using regular inline code with objects works much better <%if (mydata.MyProp!=""){%><div><%=mydata.MyProp%></div><%}%> ... Case closed I guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div runat="server" visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MyProp") as string) %>'>
    <%# Eval("MyProp") %>
</div>
```

---

**Edit 2010/9/30**

Now that I have a little time I feel like I should expand on my answer. Especially considering that the question is a duplicate that already has [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462141/eval-in-if-statement/3462310#3462310) than my original. So I will tackle the first part of your question:

Why can you not combine if and eval? The reason is that `<% ... %>` code blocks are executed during the *render phase* of the page lifecycle. ASP.NET puts your code (the if statement in this case) into a function, then passes that function as a delegate to [SetRenderMethodDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.setrendermethoddelegate.aspx). The problem is that [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.eval.aspx) evaluates your expression "MyProp" on the object returned by [Page.GetDataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getdataitem.aspx). *Page.GetDataItem* is a bit of magic that only returns a value if there has been a call to [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) earlier in the call stack. By the time the render phase comes around, all the data binding has finished.  Hence when you call *Eval*, which implicitly calls *Page.GetDataItem*, the following error is thrown: "Databinding methods [...] can only be used in the context of a databound control."

So `<% ... %>` code blocks won't work, but what about `<%# ... %>` code blocks, a.k.a. [data-binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)? Data-binding expressions do run in the desired part of the page lifecycle—within a call to *DataBind*. However, the operative word here is *expression*. An `if` statement is not an expression. Anything you throw between `<%# ... %>` will be evaluated by the compiler as an expression. If you put a statement in there, the compiler will throw an error.

Hence we arrive at the idiom of calling *Eval* in a data-binding expression on the *Visible* property of a control. Eval is compatible with data-binding expressions; writing an expression is sufficient to assign the value of a property; and the *Visible* property is able to achieve an effect similar to that of using an inline `if` statement.
Final tip: if you ever end up in a situation where you don't have any existing control to naturally add a *Visible* condition to, you can always use [<asp:PlaceHolder>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx), a control that doesn't add any tags to the markup.

Comment: visible="False" would work, but not such an elegant solution, u think?

Comment: Thinking of it again - that is indeed a nice solution and it will leave out the whole tag from the markup. (My first thought was it would add style="display:none".) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was the solution I was struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Eval("MyProp")` returns object and you cannot compare object to string. You might need to cast it to string (if `MyProp` is of type string of course).

Comment: Didnt work for me, and googling around I really think it's a dead end.

Answer (score -1):

```
<% if ((string)Eval("MyProp") != "")
 { %>
<div>
    <%# Eval("MyProp") %></div>
<%} %>
```

or

```
<%# (string)Eval("MyProp") != "" ? string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", Eval("MyProp")) : "" %>
```